# angularJS $dirty when value unchanged

Tags: angularjs

I have a form with multiple fields that the user can alter. I need to keep track of the state of the field and only allow the user to save if the value is changed. Now it looks like `$dirty` is set to `true` the moment when the value is altered even if it were changed back to the original value. Is there any way to use `$dirty` or something similar to be `true` only if the value is changed from it's original value?

*edit: okay it doesn't seem like it's possible with built in functions. Would I be better off storing all the original values? I'd avoid using `$watch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular `FormController` doesn't have any property you can use to achieve this. `$dirty` can only tell you if user has already interacted with the form. You have to watch the value and 'manually' check if it has changed.

Answer (score 0):

use $pristine No fields have been modified yet

Comment: is that not the same though? Say my original value of the field is a string. If I alter that string `$pristine` is set to false. Even if I change the string back it will stay false. I need it to recognize it as not a change when it's back to it's original value.

Comment: $pristine is just negation of $dirty and doesn't solve the problem